# Break Loop with Command

Tags: python, loops, command, break, discord

In my Python - Discord Bot, I wanted to create a command, which causes a loop to run. The loop should stop when I enter a second command. So roughly said:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!C1"):
        while True:
            if message.content.startswith("!C2"):
                break
            else:
                await client.send_message(client.get_channel(ID), "Loopstuff")
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

So it posts every 10 seconds "Loopstuff" in a Channel and stops, when I enter !C2

But I cant figure it out on my own .-.

Comment: Why not capturing a keystroke like ctrl+c to singal your loop to stop?

Comment: Everyone in the discord Channel should be able to access the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `on_message` function `message` content won't change. So another message will cause `on_message` to be called one more time. You need a synchronisation method ie. global variable or class member variable which will be changed when `!C2` message arrives.

```
keepLooping = False

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global keepLooping
    if message.content.startswith("!C1"):
        keepLooping = True
        while keepLooping:
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel(ID), "Loopstuff")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
    elif message.content.startswith("!C2"):
        keepLooping = False
```

As a side note it's good to provide a standalone example not just a single function.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

(Without trying for myself) Try:

`while not message.content.startswith("!C2")`

For the `While` clause, followed by the contents of your `else` clause.