# I used while loop for discord spam bot which gets triggered with start keyword but the loop is not breaking when I use stop keyword, how to fix it?

Tags: python, while-loop, discord.py

```
import discord
import time
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('{0.user} bot is Online'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('start'):
     while message.content != 'stop':
      await message.channel.send("Spam")
      time.sleep(.75)
```

here it gets triggered with start keyword but the loop is not breaking when I use stop keyword

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break Loop with Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824314/break-loop-with-command)

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```py
from asyncio import TimeoutError, sleep
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user!s} bot is Online')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return

    if message.content.startswith('start'):
        while 1:
            try:
                await client.wait_for(
                    'message', timeout=.75,
                     check=lambda msg, user: msg.channel == message.channel and msg.content.startswith('stop')
                )
                break
            except TimeoutError:
                pass
```